# How to properly request XML for Google Link Shortener API using API key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use my api key but I get "400 Bad Request" Here is my function (I need the ext. part):

```
//k1 is input like "ToKCqn"
//k2 is api key
ext.secret = function(k1, k2) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open ('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2F'+ k1 +'&fields=longUrl&key={' + k2 +'}', false);
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
};
```

Please tell me what is wrong with the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand what you want, if you are trying to expand a long url then i suggest you look at google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand,

I checked this function in codepen and it worked,

```
ext.secret = function(k1, k2) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open ('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/'+ k1+"&key="+k2, false);
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
};
```

Google returned 200 OK

```
{
    "kind": "urlshortener#url",
    "id": "http://goo.gl/ENzUcd",
    "longUrl": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nvidia-GeForce-Graphics-Express-Display/dp/B00BKV3EVK",
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why the API key doesn't work, but I got 200 OK! Great help!

Comment: From what the documentation showed, it doesn't look like you need an api key, however it looks odd that you put the key in between {}, but that is just opinion not fact. Glad I could help

Comment: I copied from (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/urlshortener/v1/urlshortener.url.get?shortUrl=http%253A%252F%252Fgoo.gl%252FENzUcd&_h=1&) , or the GET request and made changes `GET https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FENzUcd&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
`